# Click functions do not fire without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, click

Ok, I have seen this ask many times, and even solutions thant work for other users. But none has satisfied my need.

In a nutshell, I am using Jquery Mobile a a UI for a touch screen desktop browser application.

My index page contains only 2 jqm pages (#page1, #page2), every click event works fine within the DOM ready function. However when I change to an external page after #page2 via

```
$.mobile.changePage("newPage.php?param1=1&param2=2"), { transition : "slide"} );
```

Parameters get passed just fine, however, none of my click events work now without requiring a page refresh. When I reload the page everything is gravy, but then i notice again if i navigate back to my index page from the external page, I continue to have the same problem unless a refresh is done.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated....noting out there has even remotely worked. And I am not going to use a page refresh as a work around. Thank you in advance.

My apologies for no code example, I thought my problem was rather trivial. Here it goes..

**Document 1(index.php) Javascript**

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    ////////Home Functions
    $( "#issueSpinCoilBtn").click(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage( "#issueToSpin1", { transition : "slide"} );
    });
    $( "#issueRollBalanceBtn").click(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage( "#issueToRollBalance1", { transition : "slide"} );
    });

      /////////Issue To spin page 1 functions
   $( "#11InBtn").click(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage( "#issueToSpin2", { transition : "slide"} );
    });
    $( "#15InBtn").click(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage( "#issueToSpin2", { transition : "slide"} );
    });
    $( "#18InBtn").click(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage( "#issueToSpin2", { transition : "slide"} );
    })
    $( "#navRestartFromSpinPage1").click(function() {
         $.mobile.changePage( "#home", { transition : "slide"} );
         $("#selectionsForm")[0].reset();
    });



    $( "#findCoilBtn1").click(function() {

        $.mobile.changePage( "issueToSpinResults1.php?width="+ $('input[name=widthRadio]:checked').val() + "&gauge=" + $('input[name=gaugeRadio]:checked').val() + "&color=" + $("#selectColor").val(), { transition : "slide"} );

         $("#selectionsForm")[0].reset();

    });

});///END DOM READY

</script>
```

**Document 1(index.php) HTML Body**

```
        <body>

    <div data-role="page" class="ui-body-a" id="home" name="home">

        <div data-role="header">
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="padding:50px;">
            <h1>Please select form the following options:</h1>
       <div align="center">

       <input id="issueSpinCoilBtn2" name="issueSpinCoilBtn2" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="top" value="Issue Spin Coil Inventory" type="button"><br /><br /><br />

        <input id="issueSpinCoilBtn" name="issueSpinCoilBtn" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="top" value="Issue Spin Coil Inventory from NON TRACKED LOT" type="button"><br /><br /><br />
        <input id="issueRollBalanceBtn" name="issueRollBalanceBtn" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="top" value="Issue Roll Balance Inventory" type="button">
    </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-fullscreen="true" data-position="fixed">
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->



    <div data-role="page" class="ui-body-a" id="issueToSpin1" name="issueToSpin1">

        <div data-role="header">

    </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="padding:50px;">
            <h1 align="center">Issuing to Spin Coil Inventory from NON TRACKED LOT</h1><br />
       <div align="center">
    <form id="selectionsForm" name="selectionsForm">

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-inline="true">
        <legend align="center"><h3>Select Coil Width:</h3></legend>
            <input name="widthRadio" id="widthRadio1" value="11.8750" type="radio">
            <label for="widthRadio1">11.8750"</label>
            <input name="widthRadio" id="widthRadio2" value="15.0000" type="radio">
            <label for="widthRadio2">15.0000"</label>
            <input name="widthRadio" id="widthRadio3" value="18.0000" type="radio">
            <label for="widthRadio3">18.0000"</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-inline="true">
        <legend align="center"><h3>Select Coil Gauge:</h3></legend>
            <input name="gaugeRadio" id="gaugeRadio1" value=".0270" type="radio">
            <label for="gaugeRadio1">0.027"</label>
            <input name="gaugeRadio" id="gaugeRadio2" value=".0320" type="radio">
            <label for="gaugeRadio2">0.032"</label>
    </fieldset>
    <span data-inline="true">
    <label for="selectColor" class="select"><h3 align="center">Select a Color</h3></label>
    <select name="selectColor" id="selectColor" data-native-menu="false">
     <option>Colors</option>
         <?
     while ($rowAllColors = mssql_fetch_array($allColorQuery)) {
        echo "<option value=\"$rowAllColors[ColorCode]\">$rowAllColors[ColorName]</option>";     

     }


     ?>
 </select>
    </span>
    </form>
        </div>
        </div><!-- /content --> 
    <div data-role="footer" style="overflow:hidden;" data-fullscreen="true" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <!-- <li><a id="navBackFromSpin1" name="navBackFromSpin1" href="#" data-icon="arrow-l">Go Back</a></li> -->
                <li><a id="navRestartFromSpinPage1" name="navRestartFromSpinPage1" data-icon="refresh">Start Over</a></li>
                 <li><a id="findCoilBtn1" name="findCoilBtn1" data-icon="arrow-r" data-rel="external" >Find Coil</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
```

**Document 2(issueToSpinResults1.php) Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#goBackToOptions').click(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "index.php#issueToSpin1", { transition : "slide"} ); 
        });
        $('#navRestart').click(function() {
            $.mobile.changePage( "index.php", { transition : "slide"} ); 
        });

         $('#printTagBtn').click(function() { 
        var datastring = "itemID=" + $('input[name=coilChoice]:checked').val() + "&weight=" +  $('#coil_weight').html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "doCreateSpinTag1.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {

                $.mobile.changePage( "index.php", { transition : "slide"} );
            }
        }); 



        });



         $('#0').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '0' )
        });
        $('#1').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '1' )
        });
        $('#2').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '2' )
        });
        $('#3').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '3' )
        });
        $('#4').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '4' )
        });
        $('#5').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '5' )
        });
        $('#6').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '6' )
        });
        $('#7').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '7' )
        });
        $('#8').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '8' )
        });
        $('#9').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html( $('#coil_weight').html() + '9' )
        });
        $('#backspace').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html(
            function(index,value){
                 return value.substr(0,value.length-1);
            })
        });
        $('#clear').click(function() { 
            $('#coil_weight').html('');
        }); 
 });///END DOM READY
```

**Document 2(issueToSpinResults1.php) HTML**

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" class="ui-body-a" id="spinresults1" name="spinresults1">

    <div data-role="header">
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content" style="padding:50px;">
        <h1>Here is what we found:</h1>
   <div align="center">


     <?
     ///////////select all matching coil//////  


     if(mssql_num_rows($coilMatchesQuery) != 0){
         echo "<fieldset data-role=\"controlgroup\">
                <legend>Select Coil and Enter Weight to Create Tag:</legend>";
         $i = 1;
         while ($rowCoilMatches = mssql_fetch_array($coilMatchesQuery)) {
            echo "<input name=\"coilChoice\" id=\"coilChoice$i\" value=\"".trim($rowCoilMatches['ItemNo'])."\" type=\"radio\">
            <label for=\"coilChoice$i\">".trim($rowCoilMatches['ItemNo'])." - ".trim($rowCoilMatches['Description'])."</label>";     
            $i++;
        }
        echo "</fieldset>";
     }//End If
     else{
         echo "<h3>0 Coil Matches</h3>";
     }//End Else


 ?>

<div id="weight" align="center">

 <h2 align="center">Enter Weight</h2>
</div>

           <div align="center" style="font-size:36px; font-weight:bold;"><span id="coil_weight" style="font-size:36px; font-weight:bold;"></span>&nbsp;LBS</div>
               <br />

             <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" width="400px">
  <tr>
    <td width="33%"><input id="7" type="button" value="7"></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="8" type="button" value="8"></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="9" type="button" value="9" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%"><input id="4" type="button" value="4" ></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="5" type="button" value="5" ></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="6" type="button" value="6" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%"><input id="1" type="button" value="1" ></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="2" type="button" value="2" ></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="3" type="button" value="3" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%"><input id="0" type="button" value="0"></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="backspace" type="button" value="&larr;BKSP" ></td>
    <td width="33%"><input id="clear" type="button" value="CLEAR"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  </tr>
</table> 


<div style="width:400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"><a href="" data-iconpos="right" data-icon="arrow-r" data-role="button" id="printTagBtn">Print Coil Tag</a></div> 

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" style="overflow:hidden;" data-fullscreen="true" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>

            <li><a id="navRestart" name="navRestart" data-icon="refresh" data-transition="slide" >Start Over</a></li>
             <li><a id="goBackToOptions" name="goBackToOptions" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" >Change Options</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


</body>
```

Hopefully this will clarify a few things. Thank you all again.

Comment: Perhaps if you put a [minimal, complete example of the problem](http://sscce.org) in the question, it would help people help you.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're code isn't properly setup. When you navigate onsite pages they get carried around in the Dom. But if you refresh a page or navigate away this is essentially hitting the epage directly and not using ajax. Therefore its possible youre losing script or its simply not being called. You need to look at the functions and any page events these are linked to. Some code would help us debug it with you.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that `$.mobile.changePage` is deprecated, you might wnat to consider using [PageContainer.change()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change) instead.

With the limited information, it might be hard to give you a full answer. *My assumption* is that you are using `$("selector").click(...)` to define click events.

When changePage loads new content dynamically, the new buttons do not have `onclick` events bound to them.

Your best option is to use:

```
$(document).on("click", "selector", ...handler...);
```

Comment: pagecontainer.change() leaves form elements visible..?? And no luck with document on click...tried that one before :(              Thank you!

Comment: I stand corrected...pagecontainer.change is working well I did not specify the correct selector. Still no luck with click though :/   thanks!